# Preload pdf file then redirect

Tags: php, javascript, pdf

I have large pdf files on my website and i would like to display a "the pdf file is loading" page while the pdf is loading. And once it's loaded redirect automaticaly to the pdf file.

Is there a way to do it?

If anyone has an idea on how to do this it would be great.

Answer (score 0):

With Ajax http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Also you use this method:

First show the element(for ex. `<div class="loading"></div>`) where written ("PDF loading"). and then when your PDF is loaded you hide that element.

```
$("pdf container").load(function(){
$(".loading").hide();
});
```